# Let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$ and $N\unlhd G $ s.t. $|N|=p$. Find ${\rm Aut}(N)$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

> Let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $|G|$ and $N\unlhd G $ s.t. $|N|=p$. Find ${\rm Aut}(N)$.

Attempt:

We have $|N|=p$ and since $p$ is a prime number, $N$ is a cyclic subgroup and so abelian, hence $Z(N)=N$.

Also ${\rm Inn}(N) \cong N/Z(N)$ can be obtained from the first isomorphism theorem.

Since $Z(N)=N\space$ we obtain  ${\rm Inn}(N) \cong N/N=\{e\}$  so

$${\rm Out}(N)= {\rm Aut}(N)/{\rm Inn}(N)\implies {\rm Out}(N)={\rm Aut}(N)$$

Is my solution correct?

I will be grateful for feedback. Thanks!

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry , a typo

Comment: Note $$G/\{ e_G\}\neq G;$$ rather, $$G/ \{ e_G\}\cong G$$ for all groups $G$.

Comment: No, you don't have a solution. You only said that $Out(N)\cong Aut(N)$. We simply have the following: if $|N|=p_1$ then $N\cong C_{p_1}$ and we have ${\rm Aut}(N)\cong C_{p_1-1}$.

Comment: I would have expected the question to be "show $N \le Z(G) $".

Comment: Most of the problem set-up is useless. That $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, the order of $G$, none of that matters in any way whatsoever. Your question boils down to "I have a group of order $p_1$ a prime, and I want to find its automorphism group. Why include the dross?

Comment: I don't get the downvotes here. There's a clear attempt.

Comment: @Shaun Now it is better. The original post had several problems ($N$ and $G$ interchanged, a prime factorization introduced and never used etc.). Nevertheless, I still don't understand why the outer automorphism group is mentioned. I also suspect that the real question is a different one, namely to show that $N$ is normal, see  [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825321/if-a-subgroup-has-smallest-prime-index-then-it-is-normal). Why? Because of the wording "smallest prime divisor" in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done is two steps:

1. [Show that every group of prime order is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106163/104041)
2. Show [Aut $\mathbb Z_p\simeq \mathbb Z_{p-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361651/104041)